# How do you re-write a C++ empty if statement with side-effects

Tags: c++

I have code that does something like this:

```
//datareader.cpp
if (populateFoo(dataReader, foo))
else {
   // Do other things with the reader.
}

//foo.cpp
bool populateFoo(const DataReader &dataReader, Foo &foo)
{
   if (dataReader.name() == "bar") {
      foo.bar() = dataReader.value();
      return true;
   } // More similar checks.
   return false;
}
```

I feel like it's misleading to have an if statement with conditions that have side-effects. However, I can't move the body of the populateFoo function into datareader.cpp. Is there a good way to restructure this code so we get rid of this misleading if statement, without duplicating the body of populateFoo()?

Comment: `bool readSucceeded = populateFoo(); if (readSucceeded)` you've now documented the side effect and it's no longer misleading. Problem solved.

Comment: Seperate the check from the side-effect.

Comment: I really don't think there is anything to fix here. Your code is fine. At a push, you could change the name of the function to `tryPopulateFoo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a strong hatred of local variables? If not:

```
bool populated = populateFoo(dataReader, foo);

if (populated)
{
  // Do things
}
else 
{
  // Do other things
}
```

The compiler will almost certainly emit *exactly* the same code, so performance shouldn't be an issue. It's a readability/style choice, ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution seems like storing the result of populateFoo and using it for determining whether populateFoo was successful:

```
bool fooPopulated = populateFoo(dataReader, Foo);
if (!fooPopulated)
    //Do other things with reader.
```

However, I don't find the original difficult to understand, and it's a fairly well-established practice to both modify values and test the success of the modification in the same line.  However, I would change it to:

```
if (!populateFoo(dataReader, Foo)
    //Do other things with reader.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (!populateFoo(dataReader, foo)) {
    // Do other things with the reader.
}
```

Edit: The title of the question suggests it is the fact the `if` statement is empty that bothers you but the body seems more that it is the side effect that is the concern. I think it's fine in C++ to have conditions in `if` statements that have side effects but this won't solve your issue if you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Having conditions with side-effects is quite common - think about calling a C API and checking its return code for errors.

Usually, as long as it's not buried in a complicated expression where it may be missed by the casual bystander, I don't bother to do particular refactorings, but, in case you wanted to make it extra clear (or document what the return value is, which is particularly useful in case of booleans) just assign it to a variable before the branch - or even just a few comments may help.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the `populateFoo` function into two, a const check function (`shouldPopulateFoo`) that checks the condition, and another non-const function that performs the actual modifications (`populateFoo`):

```
//datareader.cpp
if (shouldPopulateFoo(dataReader)) {
    populateFoo(dataReader, foo);
}
else {
    // Do other things with the reader.
}

//foo.cpp
bool shouldPopulateFoo(const DataReader &dataReader) /* const */
{
   return (dataReader.name() == "bar");
}

void populateFoo(const DataReader &dataReader, Foo &foo) /* non-const */
{
    assert(shouldPopulateFoo(dataReader));
    foo.bar = dataReader.value();
}
```

Note that when using these functions as class methods, you could declare the check function const.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far... often the only way to check if something can/should be done involves the same steps as actually doing it (or starting to do it may be the only way to do it avoiding race conditions - think DB transactions or opening files) - separating the two steps in most cases would lead to worse performance, duplicated logic in separate places (which inevitably falls out of sync) and all in all less clear/maintainable code.

Comment: I only wanted to point out that this option exists. I agree that often it makes no sense to "artificially" split code into a check function and one that does the modifications. But in some cases (e.g. for writing tests) it may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (populateFoo(dataReader, foo) == false) {
// Do other things with the reader.
}
```

It is very readable, I often see code where the returned value from function is a **signal** to the caller for branching in the caller.  The `else` block with empty `if` block bothers me more then the side effects inside the `if ()`.  There is a sense of reverse logic, which is alway less readable.